# Any algorithm in literature to solve my problem? Should call it "Segment ordering"?

Tags: order-theory, discrete-optimization, packing-problem

A slot with length $L$. I have $n$ segments, they have a positive integer length $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$, respectively, and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i = L$. My goal is to fill the slot with these segments such that, for example, the distance between the $i$th segment and the $j$th segment is minimized, subject to some constraints, i.e., the 1st segment must be located in front of the 3rd, etc. These constraints always separate the segment $i$ and $j$ (they are not adjacent, no trivial solution).

Consider a simple example. A slot with length 12 and 4 segments with length $x_1=7, x_2=2, x_3=2, x_4=1$. I want to fill the slot such that the distance between the 4th segment and 2nd segment is minimized, subject to the constraints that 1st and 3rd segment must be located behind the 2nd slot but in front of the 4th slot. For this problem, only two feasible solutions exist, i.e., $[x_2, x_1, x_3, x_4]$ and $[x_2, x_3, x_1, x_4]$. Both of them lead to an optimal solution x_1+x_3=7+2=9, if you define the distance by the difference between the starting of $x_4$ and the ending of $x_2$ (it does not matter how you define the distance since the length of segments is fixed).

Is there any algorithm in literature corresponding to my problem? Or anyone has an idea how to formulate/solve this problem in general? I don't know if the title of my post is accurate enough. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The brute force approach will require checking $n!$ permutations for feasibility and comparing those that are for optimality.  Your description of what constraints and objectives are lacks much generality; it is a "for instance" style write-up.  This makes it difficult to apply mathematical reasoning.

Comment: My constraints depend on a graph. So it is hard to describe them in general. I am just trying to see if there is any state-of-the-art algorithm which I don't know the name, but can solve this kind of problem (something like pin packing). Specifically, I have an n node (correspond to segments) directed graph, if node k is point to node p, them k must be located behind p. That's all I can say since the graph is also a variable.

Comment: Assuming the objective is always of the form "minimize the distance between segment $i$ and segment $j$", you can trim the search space by first looking for feasible solutions where those two segments are adjacent (obviously they can be transposed without affecting the objective or feasibility), then cases where they are separated by the shortest of the remaining segments, etc.  There are other ways to trim the search space, but in the worst case you will have to search the entire $n!$ space to satisfy feasibility.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath . I am sorry I forgot to mention constraints always separate segment $i$ and $j$ (no trivial solution). Thanks a lot for your help. I just want to check if any state-of-the-art algorithm that I am not aware may exist. You are right, the worst case I will try exhaustive search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is a known problem, but it can be solved in linear time. View the problem as a directed graph $G$, with vertices $V(G) = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ and an edge $uv$ whenever "$u$ precedes $v$" is a constraint. Finding a feasible solution to your problem is simply a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of this graph.

To find an optimal solution, you want to guide your topological sort. For now, assume $x_i$ must precede $x_j$ (add the edge $x_ix_j$ if necessary). Begin with a "$x_i$-phobic topological sort", where we refuse to add $x_i$ to the list (i.e., never allow $x_i \in S$ in Kahn's algorithm from the wiki page), obtaining a list $L_1$. Now, perform a $x_j$-phobic topological sort, but follow edges backwards, obtaining a list $L_2$. Reverse $L_2$ to make it topologically sorted; also remove any elements in $L_1$ from it. We now simply need to add the remaining vertices between $L_1$ and $L_2$; this can be done with a topological sort rooted at $x_i$ which ignores all nodes in $L_1$ and $L_2$, obtaining a new list $L_3$. We finally construct $L = (L_1,L_3,L_2)$ as our answer.

The above certainly produces a topological sort (i.e., a feasible solution). I claim it is also optimal, and in fact, any element $x_k$ between $x_i$ and $x_j$ in $L$ *must* be between them for any feasible solution. Since $x_k$ is not in $L_1$, one can show that there is a path from $x_i$ to $x_k$; thus, $x_i$ must precede $x_k$. Similarly, since $x_k$ also wasn't found by $L_2$, there is a path from $x_k$ to $x_j$ (i.e., a path from $x_j$ to $x_k$ when the edges were reversed), so $x_k$ must precede $x_j$. Thus, our algorithm is optimal. Since topological sorting is linear in $|V(G)| + |E(G)|$, this is a linear-time algorithm.

Note that we have to run this process once for forcing $x_ix_j$, and once for $x_jx_i$. Also note that the segment lengths didn't matter.

Comment: Nice connection to topological sort/order-extension principle.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the connection to topological sorting is very helpful. Do you think a similar algorithm can also be designed for minimizing $|x_j-x_i| + |x_p-x_q| + \cdots + |x_w-x_v| $, i.e., the total distance for several pairs of segments?

Comment: I noticed that there are algorithms giving all the solutions of topological sorting, that can definitely solve the problem. But your idea to solve the distance for a pair nodes really simplifies the problem a lot.

Comment: That will make things a lot more complicated. Let $S_{a,b}$ represent the set of segments that *must* come after $x_a$ and before $x_b$ (i.e., things with a path from $x_a$ and a path to $x_b$ in $G$). In the original problem, the segments between $x_i$ and $x_j$ in an optimal solution are exactly $S_{i,j}$. In the new problem, it won't be possible in general to do this for every pair. I'm not sure if there's a clever solution.

As you noted, topological sorting will help you brute-force efficiently. You can further speed this up with branch-and-bound pruning.